# Search string in two different colums

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I been trying to solve this problem, I have my fullname table splitted in 2, 'nombre' for name and 'apellido' for the lastname, the thing is that sometimes they have 2 names and 1 lastname for example: `[name: ANTONIO DAMIAN] [lastname: RAFANIELLO]`

I get a single `$name` for the full search, currently this is my search

```
    $nombre = request('query');
    $socios = Socio::where('nombre', 'like', "%{$nombre}%")
                            ->orWhere('apellido', 'like', "%{$nombre}%")
                            ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat(nombre, ' ', apellido)"), 'like', "%".$nombre."%")
                            ->orWhere('documento', 'like', "%{$nombre}%")
                            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                            ->paginate($this->paginateNumber)
                            ->appends(['query'=>$nombre]);
```

The part of the code that should be working is `->orWhere(DB::raw("concat(nombre, ' ', apellido)"), 'like', "%".$nombre."%")` but if I search `antonio rafaniello` it show empty search.

Also if I try the raw sql `SELECT * FROM socio WHERE concat(nombre, ' ', apellido) = '%antonio rafaniello%'`
 either shows anything

I've been looking other awnsers here but none of them helped me, help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
$nombre = request('query');
$socios = Socio::where('nombre', 'like', "%{$nombre}%")
                        ->orWhere(DB::raw("concat(nombre, ' ', apellido)"), 'like', "%".strtr($nombre,' ','%')."%")
                        ->orWhere('documento', 'like', "%{$nombre}%")
                        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                        ->paginate($this->paginateNumber)
                        ->appends(['query'=>$nombre]);
```

But be carfull with full scan... :(

**Edited - Explanation:**

The change is in `strtr($nombre,' ','%')` where he changes the spaces with % so the sql would take each word separately for the SELECT

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that other can learn from it